# Any neater way for plain Html pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My app has some good quantity of plain web pages. Is there a short cut for the below:

```
public ActionResult page1()
{  return View(); }
public ActionResult page2()
{  return View(); }
public ActionResult page3()
{  return View(); }
public ActionResult page4()
{  return View(); }
public ActionResult page5()
{  return View(); }
//....
public ActionResult page48()
{  return View(); }
```

Comment: I'd set them up as partial views with the view name as the parameter.

Comment: Do you mean having another `/` in the url?

Comment: Do these pages need to be processed by Razor or the MVC runtime?

Comment: @mxmissile Yes, for the layout (master) page, so that they have the same look and feel as pages that require code.

Comment: So what is your problem?... If you have different views that need sto be rendered as views with their own content you need to have corresponding Actionresults. I don't see the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [HandleUnknownAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.handleunknownaction(v=vs.118).aspx)

> Called when a request matches this controller, but no method with the specified action name is found in the controller.

So you can create a controller for your pages which just handles the `HandleUnknownAction` method and will return the view if it exists

```
 namespace TEST.Controllers
 {
     [HandleError]
     public class PagesController : Controller
     {

         protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
         {
              this.View(actionName).ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
          }
      }
 }
```

So if you have a controller named pages with views `page1.cshtml` `page2.cshtml` `page3.cshtml` etc you could call them with `pages/page1` without stuffing the controller with repeated code

In the actual view you then just add

```
@{
    Layout = "layoutpath";
 }
```

Because when you create the view by default that will be null

[More info here](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/07/21/asp-net-mvc-tip-22-return-a-view-without-creating-a-controller-action)

Comment: I did not know about this, neat.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Works as advertised.

Comment: @gerdi Related but separate question: Is there a way to pass a model to ExecuteResult?  If view is not found I want to call this.View("error").ExecuteResult... and pass along a HandleErrorInfo object.

Comment: @OldGeezer I havnt tried this but you could try adding the property View for the attribute `[HandleError(View="ViewName"]` . Check out more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are simply returning some HTML and are only using the razor syntax due to inclusion of a layout file, I would recommend using `WebPages`.  These are essentially razor `cshtml` dynamic files that will process without having to go through a controller/action.

To start, confirm that `WebPages` is turned on in your web.config (if it is not already on) by looking for this line: `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />`. Next, simply treat these `.cshtml` files as standalone files (no controller/actions needed).  You could move all of these to some root folder and link to them from there.  Assuming you are using a folder called HTML...

- Project Root

  - HTML

    - page1.cshtml
    - page2.cshtml

Then, you should be able to get any page to render by going to `http://yourwebsite.com/HTML/page2.cshtml`.  In your HTML, the markup would be the same as if you linked to any other static resource.

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/HTML/page2.cshtml")">Link</a>
```

Please [refer here](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started) for more information on WebPages